# Android Development: multiple tables or a huge single table whilst designing database?

Tags: android, mysql, database

I am developing an android app and I am required to save data which needs to be distinguished via date of entry.

To do this, I've thought of these approaches:

1. Create a new table for each date and store the data in it.
   Thus, the table would consist of only 2 attributes, i.e item_number and amount
2. Create a huge table which also contains the date attribute and unique_id.

Would making multiple tables make it simpler to add data belonging to a specific date? However would it also degrade performance or take up more space?

Comment: MySQL does not run on Android. Is this a MySQL question, or an Android question?

Comment: Maybe you meant sqlite? If that's the issue, it has nothing to do with Android.

Comment: My mistake, I meant sqlite. Since, I am working on Android, I mentioned it.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the huge table should be great because you have just two fields and one can have upto 1 billion rows easily in mysql database. Also the Idea of having multiple tables is fine as it would keep things in normalized form. The choice is yours really.

You can also have tables split in years(if you are spliting why not year wise?). As I believe it would act much like acting like an archive,also normalized and number of rows would not hit above some 100 billion.